# Command to download bunch of folders sharing generic names using sftp

Tags: sftp

I am running multiple codes in clusters creating multiple folders. I have some difficulties downloading them using the command `get`. Indeed what I use to do is to download folder by folder. Since the folders usually share generic names such as `W1, W2, W3, ....`.

Is there a command in sftp to download them using as argument `W*` (for instance) in `sftp`?

Comment: I found `mget` and `mput` working on getting multiple folders with `sftp`. But when I type on the `sftp` prompt the command `help` they are not listed among the command. I wonder why?